# ImageButtons wont change Image after being pressed - LibGDX

Tags: java, android, user-interface, libgdx

I am currently working on a menue screen in libgdx. I added a **ImageButton**
to the screen, but when i want to start the app and click on the button the image wont change state from button-up image to button-down image. Furthermore, adding a Listener, which adds an action to the button, doesnt take any effect whatsoever. I guess it has something to do with the **addActor()** function not working correct?

```
public class Test extends UIScreen {
 public Test(final MainExecute test) {
        super();
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage = new Stage();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        table = new Table();
        txture = new createTexture();
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("atlases/main/unnamed.atlas");

        table.left();
        table.top();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.setDebug(true);
        background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ui elements and skins/Settings screen/Background.png"));
        Texture up = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ui elements and skins/Settings screen/Settings.png"));
        Drawable upDraw = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(up));
        Texture down = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ui elements and skins/Settings screen/Settings Pressed.png"));
        Drawable downDraw = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(down));


        ImageButton settings = new ImageButton(upDraw, downDraw);
        table.add(settings).pad(30).expand();
        this.stage.addActor(table);

        settings.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        batch.end();
        this.stage.act(delta);
        this.stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        this.viewport.update(width, height);
        this.camera.position.set(this.camera.viewportWidth / 2, this.camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        this.camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }
}
```

> UIScreen

```
   public UIScreen() {
        //Initialising camera and adding viewport
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);
        viewport.apply();
        //Camera position, watching for full screen
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        camera.update();
        //Adding the viewport to the stage
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport(new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight())));
        stage.setDebugAll(true);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are creating a new Stage instance in show(), overwriting the one you created in UIScreen. Therefore the stage isn't set as InputProcessor.

Just remove the first line `stage = new Stage();` in the show method and it should be working fine.

Edit: Also you have to access stage with `super.stage` instead of `this.stage`, and make sure it is visible to Test.

Comment: Without more information, it's hard to help. Also you have to access the stage with super.stage instead of this.stage and make sure it is visible to Test. You can either declare stage public/protected in UIScreen or write a getter for it.

Comment: You dont have to use `super.stage`. `this.stage` is a valid accessor. @Quentin